# Provide TabIndex number into angularJs ng grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, tabindex

I am using ng grid and each row of the grid have a text box. I want to access all the textbox inside and outside of the grid using TAB Key according to provided tabIndex.

My plunker is here : http://plnkr.co/edit/ce4xnHJtYhRdwe6JvZSA?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

set noTabInterference: true in gridOptions, updated recently

Comment: using noTabInterference, you can not specify customize tabindex